# Express route parsing

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to create a route for the following URL:

```
http://localhost:5000/api/querystring?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2
```

My route looks like this:

```
app.get('/api/:querystring/:parameter1?/:parameter2?', function(req, res) {

   // do stuff
})
```

How can I create a route that matches the given URL?

Answer (score 1):

You can't include query string parts in the route ... you will have to leave them off.

```
app.get('/api/querystring' ...
```

Then in the callback you can look at `req.query` to see the parameters.  If you were to compare to the query, the order of the query string parameters would matter.  It shouldn't.

If you want `/api/querystring?parameter1=foo` and `/api/querystring?parameter2=bar` to use different routes, you will have to handle this by calling separate functions within the `app.get` route callback above.

Comment: Instead of "calling separate functions within the `app.get` route callback", what you could do is have the same two GET routes, but add an `if (!req.query.parameter1) return next();` in the first one and then add a `if (!req.query.parameter2) return next();` in the second one.